# Ensuring unique IP addresses in ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

Say I want the same AMI image to run in two different ec2 instances with different IPs.

Will suffice by ensuring a different AWS location or do I need to specifically allocate different VPCs for each instance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance will have a unique IP address. You certainly don't need to separate them into different VPCs or anything. An AMI does not have a specific IP address tied to it. Each time you create an instance from an AMI the new instance will have a unique IP address. If that wasn't the case, auto-scaling wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Why would autoscaling not work without new fresh IPs?

Comment: Autoscaling deploys multiple EC2 instances based on a single AMI, into a single VPC. If they each had the same IP it wouldn't work.